R: running a mirai_cluster via parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK
my goal is to perform some heavy computation in R on a cluster of several Linux hosts, using docker containers.
Within R I want to use foreach.
To do this, I believe the best approach is with the futureverse.
Since I want the system to be able to use more then 125 cores, I want to use the future.mirai backend.
Also I want to have some fine grain control over the way the cluster is set up, e.g. to have it run in docker containers.
Thats why I want to use makeClusterPSOCK (see Section 5 of the Examples).
This whole setup feels rather complicated to me, so I start with a very small example on my Windows 11 laptop (8 cores) and try to bootstrap myself up from there.
Currently my problem is that I lack any tutorial/example/documentation how I can combine the different parts of the futureverse into a bigger unity.
Here is an MWE:
rm(list = ls())
.rs.restartR()

library(doFuture)
library(future.mirai)

########################

# plan(sequential)
# plan(multisession)

# plan(mirai_multisession)
# plan(mirai_cluster)

# plan(cluster, workers = c("n1", "n2", "n3"))

workers <- rep("localhost", parallelly::availableCores())
cl <- parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK(
  workers = workers,
  dryrun = FALSE,
  verbose = TRUE,
  autoStop = TRUE)

plan(cluster, workers = cl)

#plan(mirai_cluster, workers = cl)

# Error in MiraiFuture(expr = expr, substitute = FALSE, envir = envir, workers = NULL, : 
# formal argument “workers” matches several given arguments
# Additionally: warning message:
# Detected 1 unknown future arguments: 'workers' 

##############################

y <- foreach(x = 1:1000, .combine = c) %dofuture% {
  Sys.getpid()
}
table(y)

The idea here is to try out the different strategies (sequential,multisession,mirai_multisession) and check that the number of pids is what I expect it to be.
How can I overcome the 125 core limit in this scenario (how can I combine the future.mirai backend with parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK)?

I haven't tried but possibly plan(cl) could work? However, I think you should look at the example in help("mirai_cluster").

author of Futureverse here.
Using 'multisession'
In R (>= 4.4.0) [2024-04-24], you can increase the number of connections that R can handle when you launch R and Rscript by specifying options --max-connection=N, e.g.
$ Rscript --max-connections=512 -e "parallelly::availableConnections()"
[1] 512

This is documented in https://parallelly.futureverse.org/reference/availableConnections.html. This means you can use multisession with, say 148 parallel workers (one connection per worker) + some spare connection for other purposes by using:
$ R --max-connections=192
...
> library(future)
> plan(multisession, workers = 148)
> nbrOfWorkers()
[1] 148

> library(doFuture)
> pids <- foreach(ii = seq_len(nbrOfWorkers())) %dofuture% Sys.getpid()
> length(unique(pids))
[1] 148

Using 'future.callr::callr'
The future.callr package does not rely on connections, so you can use that as:
> library(future)
> plan(future.callr::callr, workers = 148)
> nbrOfWorkers()
[1] 148

Using 'future.mirai::mirai_multisession'
The future.mirai package does not rely on connections, so you can use that as:
> library(future)
> plan(future.mirai::mirai_multisession, workers = 148)
> nbrOfWorkers()
[1] 148


... how can I combine the future.mirai backend with parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK?

You cannot; the future.mirai backend is separate from PSOCK clusters of parallelly/parallel.
PS. Questions specific to Futureverse are probably better asked on https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/discussions/

Rscript --max-connections=512 seems to be the best option here. So the idea is that I start the master process like this and then it can uopen up 512 connections to the individual workers?

Yes, that's case.
